# Can't connect to Redis from within a Docker container (Redis::CannotConnectError)

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, redis

I have a Jenkins Pipeline that runs all tests for a Sinatra application inside a Docker container.

Here's what the Pipeline looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ruby'
            args '-u root -v /root/.ssh:/root/.ssh'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
                sh 'bundle install'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing...'
                sh 'rspec spec'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploy...'
                sh 'cap staging deploy'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Sinatra app uses Redis and I can't seem to connect to Redis from within the Docker containing that's running the tests. The Redis db is ran on a different remote server that is accessible.

I'm using `redis-rb` and the following code to access Redis:

```
REDIS_DB = Redis.new(url: 'redis://:strongpassword123@server_ip:6379')
```

But the test returns with the following error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError:
       Error connecting to Redis on server_ip:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `rescue in establish_connection'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:329:in `establish_connection'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:99:in `block in connect'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:98:in `connect'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:363:in `ensure_connected'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in process'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in `logging'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `process'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis.rb:877:in `block in get'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.0.0/lib/redis.rb:876:in `get'
```

I've tried using a local Redis server but that didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment with own DNS? Can you try ping or traceroute in the pipeline to see if you are able to reach that IP itself or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker container has the IP `172.17.0.2`. Since I have UFW (firewall) enabled I had to add a rule that allows Docker to connect to Redis on port 6379.

So doing `sudo ufw allow from 172.17.0.2 to any port 6379` solved the issue.